# Service center login do not work with outsystem credentials

Tags: outsystems

I have a user account on outsystems. I am new to the Outsystems and on learning phase. When I try to login into service center, it says "invalid username and password".

Comment: Is this your personal space? It should be the same as the login of your service studio account. However it's not really a suitable question for SO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about an user account and not related to programming,

Answer (score 0):

Here you should add 'admin' attribute when editing users. It should be in System>Users entity